# How to toggle div visibility by clicking a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a little visual novel game with multiple choice buttons, that will slightly or more change the story, images, text boxes, and such... and without javascript it's like... Quite impossible.

Or possible, but it would require dozen of thousands of pages. Who knows. I want to avoid that.

So...

Is there a way to replace, for multiple times (also 100 times when required) the content of a visible div - `id="d01"` for example - including javascript and css - with the content of another similar but invisible div, making the invisible div visible, hiding the previous, but clicking on the div itself?

I've been able to find only toggles and replacements that will work for only one time, and then go back to the first content, but I'm searching for something a bit different.

Something that changes progressively, from div one to div 100 or more.

I'm working from a smartphone, so, compilers or visual novel editors are out of reach for me. But usually websites and other little things, also with a bit of java too, worked for me. So i think it will be no big fuss.

I know everything is a bit confusing. Sorry for that.

```
<div id="d01">

<!-- Content to show at the beginning, with everything it could come
to my mind: text, buttons, images, animations... ; -->

</div>
<div id="d02" style="display:none;">

<!-- Content to show after the first click, similar to the first, but
with light changes: other text, other characters, other images... ; -->

</div>
<div id="d03" style="display:none;">

<!-- Content to show after the second click, like as above; -->

</div>
<div id="d0#"> style="display:none;">

<!-- Content to show after the n. click... U got it at this point, i think; -->

</div>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Make the question cleaner a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead having a lot of `div` in the HTML, you can just use a single `div` and dynamically replace its content using javascript

First, create a div element in the html and lets put `dialogBox` as its id

```
<div id="dialogBox">
  
</div>
```

In javascript, declare the dialogs as an array like so

```
const dialogs = [
  {
    id: '01',
    text: "Content to show at the beginning, with everything it could come to my mind: text, buttons, images, animations... ;"
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    text: "Content to show after the second click, like as above;"
  },
  {
    id: '03',
    text: "Content to show after the n. click... U got it at this point, i think;"
  }
];
```

It is up to you what to put in there but in this case, I just put `text` and `id`. `id` isn't really necessary at this moment but we can use it for querying since there will hundreds of this in the future.

Now, find and store our `div` element into a variable

```
const dialogBox = document.getElementById('dialogBox');
```

Finally, we can now update/replace our `div` content.
In this example, we'll be updating the content on each mouse clicks

```
let index = 0;
dialogBox.innerHTML = dialogs[index].text

window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  index = (index < dialogs.length - 1) ? ++index : index;
  dialogBox.innerHTML = dialogs[index].text
});
```

In the above example, we set the `div` innerHTML which its content, to the current dialog text. Then, increment the `index` value by 1 on each mouse click then update the innerHTML again.

And we are done!

Comment: Thank you Theygen. It works flawlessly. But, it is possible to add pictures or other html as well as the text? If yes, could you explain how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can add almost anything as the content. How? You might want to check some tutorial on how to manipulate HTML elements using DOM. Here, check this mini project of mine
https://playcode.io/670737

Comment: WOW  Great job. I wish i was so skilled